# How can I get access token with refresh token automatically for iOS/swift?(every hour)

Tags: ios, swift

Now I'm connecting my iOS app with server.
For use the server in the app, the app need Access Token.
When user logs in, they get Access Token with Refresh Token.
So after logged in, users don't need to log in anymore. And users can use the app without logging like instagram or facebook.
But the app must update/renew access token by using refresh token every hour,
because access token expires in 3600seconds(1hour).
But how can I query/update refresh token/access token every hour?
I think the app do this every hour automatically even in background.
now I can get access token using Alamofire.
But I'm not used to use connect server with app.

My app is for iOS and coded with Swift.

Comment: you can just execute a request inside the applicationDidBecomeActive function in your AppDelegate. This function will be triggered each time you're app changing it's state from inactive (background) to active.

Comment: then how can I controll the time executing the code? (I want to do the code for every hour)

Comment: I would save the NSDate into the UserDefaults and compare the saved NSDate with the current date and if it is greater or equal to one hour then execute a call to the server. You have also the option the execute the call to the server anyway and the server will execute this logic for you.. it's better approach if your app is targeted to multiple platforms

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I can not change the server. I can just code iOS app for this API.

Comment: Then go with the first approach..

Comment: but if user restart app after 2hours from last use, the refresh token is expired. how can I do that every hour in the background?

Comment: This is a problem because you can execute stuff on the background only when the user did not remove the app from the task manager. If you want to execute background tasks while your app is in background (and was not removed from the task manager) you can read how it can be done in here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 0):

When the app is first opened by the user (comes to the foreground) you can refresh, then start a timer, say for 55 minutes. When the timer expires you can refresh. When the application goes to the background destroy the timer. Don't expect that the application should run a refresh in the background, it shouldn't and it has no reason to.

The above is all you need to do. When the app comes to the foreground you can instead check how much longer your current token is valid for and decide to not refresh and start a timer for N-5 minutes instead. And you can think about how to deal with refresh failures and no internet connection by changing the timer to run each minute perhaps...

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to implement Automatic token refreshing in mobile.

1. Manual token refresh
2. Preemptive token refresh
3. Automatic token refresh
4. Interceptor pattern
5. Silent token refresh
6. Push notification-based refresh
7. Background task-based refresh

In your case, I would like to recommend the first 3 options.

1. Manual token refresh : In this method, the mobile app explicitly checks if the access token is expired before making an API call. If it’s expired, the app sends a separate request to the server to refresh the token. To pull this off, the app needs to keep track of when the token was generated and when it’s supposed to expire. This means storing both the token expiration time and the generation time within the mobile app. With these two pieces of info, it can easily figure out if the token is still valid. This way of handling tokens gives you more control, but it might mean more back-and-forth with the server and some extra coding. Still, it’s a widely used and reliable approach in app development.
2. Preemptive token refresh : Before making any API call, the mobile app sends a request to the server to refresh the access token, regardless of whether the current token has expired. By refreshing the access token before every API call, the mobile app can guarantee that it always uses a valid token for authentication, minimising the risk of unauthorised access and ensuring a seamless user experience. However, it’s essential to consider the potential overhead of sending frequent token refresh requests and the server’s capacity to handle them efficiently. Additionally, optimising the token refresh process to minimise latency and network overhead is crucial for maintaining app performance.
3. Automatic token refresh (Client Side)  : Client-side automatic token refresh involves the mobile app calling the API in the usual manner. If the API returns a 401 error due to token expiration, the app triggers a refresh token API call from its network layer to obtain a new access token. Subsequently, the app retries the original API call with the new token without notifying the user. While this approach is widely used and reduces server overhead for preemptive token refreshing, users may experience a slight delay in accessing specific web services when the token initially expires. Implementing token refreshing within the network layer of the app can be complex, requiring adherence to architectural principles, dependency injection, and best practices.

For more details please refer the following [medium article](https://medium.com/@katramesh91/mastering-mobile-app-security-strategies-for-bulletproof-authentication-token-management-in-mobile-99ec74f8de2b), You would be able to get a fully awareness about token refreshing from this article.